# Number of positive integral solutions $(x,y)$ of $x^2-y^2=12345678$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, diophantine-equations

I have to find out the **number** of positive integral solutions $(x,y)$ of

> $$x^2-y^2=12345678$$

Specifically, if $S$ is the set of all ordered pairs $(x,y)$ then $S$ -

> A) is an infinite set
>
> B) is the empty set
>
> C) has exactly one element
>
> D) is a finite set and has at least two elements.

Now, with a calculator capable of doing prime factorization, this is an easy question. However without a calculator, its very difficult to find the prime factors by inspection. What is the most efficient and fast solution to such a question.

This question was asked [here](http://kvpy.iisc.ernet.in/main/resources/2017/SA_05-NOV-17.pdf) (Q no. 4)

Comment: @Travis Edited. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2191177/prove-that-the-equation-x2-y2-2002-has-no-integer-solution

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Thanks ;-)

Comment: As a side note; clearly the number is congruent to $2$ mod $4$ and a multiple of $9$. Division yields
$$123456789=2\times3^2\times685871.$$
A little patience with trial and error shows that $47$ is also a factor, and the remaining factor $14593$ will take a little more patience than I have right now. But it is doable in a few minutes; just check primes up to $119$.

Comment: But you _don't_ have to find out the number of solutions, do you? You just have to decide whether there are at least 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that $12345678\equiv2\pmod{4}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you suggest me some general steps I should follow in questions like this. I mean like finding the number of integral solutions to given equations. I mean what intuition drove you to think like this?

Comment: Experience: I've seen a few hundred questions concerning writing things as sums of differences of squares. The first thing to check is remainders mod $3$ and $4$, it solves or simplifies *many* such questions.

Comment: If we can counter what we get as mod $3$ or $4$ as in this case we get zero solutions. What if we can't counter?

Comment: This does not make sense; we *can* counter. If we can't then the question is different, and what approach to take depends heavily on the way the question is different.

Comment: Thanks for your input ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

$$
12345678 = 1\times 2\times 3^2\times 47\times 14593 = \prod_i a_i^{b_i}
$$

then checking the feasible solutions for

$$
x+y = \frac{\prod_i a_i^{b_i}}{m_k}\\
x-y = m_k
$$

for $m_k$ in all possible combinations between the factors, will give us the solution.