# Show not possible to find positive whole numbers $m,n$ such that $m^2 − n^2 = 6$.

Tags: solution-verification

Show not possible to find positive whole numbers $m,n$ such that $m^2 − n^2 = 6$.

$m^2 − n^2 = 6\implies (m+n)(m-n) = 6; \ m,n$ can be either even or odd.
 
If $m$ is odd, $m=2k+1, k\ge 1$; else $m=2k$. 
 
Similarly, if $n$ is odd, $n=2l+1, l\ge 1$; else $n=2l$.

There are $4$ possible cases:
 
(i) $m,n$ both are odd: $(m+n)(m-n)= 4(k+l+1)(k-l)$,
 
(ii) $m,n$ both are even: $(m+n)(m-n)= 4(k+l)(k-l)$,
 
(iii) $m,n$ one is odd, other is even: $(m+n)(m-n)= (2(k+l)+1)(2(k-l)\pm 1)$
$= 4(k+l)(k-l)+2(k-l)\pm(2(k+l)+1)$
$= 4(k+l)(k-l) +4k+1, \ \ 4(k+l)(k-l) -4l - 1$

Not possible to pursue further except by proof by contradiction.

---

If try by contradiction based proof, need prove that the premise $m^2-n^2=6$ is false:

(i) $(m+n)(m-n)= 4(k+l+1)(k-l)$
$\implies 6 = 4(k^2 + kl + k - kl -l^2 -l)= 4(k^2 -l^2 +k -l) = 4(k-l)(k+l+1)$
$\implies 3 = 2(k+l+1)(k-l)$
 
The lhs is odd, but the rhs is even.
 
(ii) $(m+n)(m-n)= 4(k+l)(k-l)$
$\implies 6 = 4(k+l)(k-l)$
 
$\implies 3 = 2(k+l)(k-l)$
 
The lhs is odd, but the rhs is even.
 
(iii) $4(k+l)(k-l) +4k+1$
$\implies 5 = 4(k+l)(k-l)+k)$
 
The lhs is odd, but the rhs is even.
 
(iv) $4(k+l)(k-l) -4l - 1$
$\implies 7 = 4(k+l)(k-l)-l)$
 
The lhs is odd, but the rhs is even.

---

However, the same cannot be said for $m^2 - n^2 = 6j, \ m,n,j \ \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: What are you asking? The question with $6$ or the one with $6j$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2191177/prove-that-the-equation-x2-y2-2002-has-no-integer-solution/2191179#2191179

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Just adding a note at end, that it is only possible to prove for $6$; not any multiple thereof.

Comment: @jiten That's because solutions do exist for higher $j$. For example, $12^2-6^2=6\cdot18$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that

$$m^2 =\sum_{k=1}^m(2k-1)\quad \text{and}\quad n^2 =\sum_{k=1}^n(2k-1)$$

Hence,

$$m^2-n^2 = \sum_{k=n+1}^m(2k-1)\stackrel{!}{=}6$$

It follows that $m\leq 3$ and $n+1\geq 2$, but the possible sums are only $3,5,3+5$. So, there is no solution.

Comment: Please elaborate your answer more, from the second line. Say, how got that $$m^2-n^2 = \sum_{k=n+1}^m(2k-1)\stackrel{!}{=}6$$ Also, the third line needs more in terms of missing steps.

Comment: It is a standard result (which can easily be verfied by induction), that $n^2$ can be formed as the sums of the first $n$ odd natural numbers. For example:
$1+3 = 2^2$, $1+3+5 = 3^3$ and so on.

Comment: In the next step I just form the difference of the sums. For example: $3^2-2^2 = (1+3+5) - (1+3) = 5$.
So, you get a sum of positive numbers that is supposed to be equal to $6$. So, the highest summand $2m-1$ is not allowed to exceed $6$.

Comment: Since we subtract at least $n=1=2\cdot 1-1$, the index $k$ of the final sum has to start at least at $k=n+1=2$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this approach.

Comment: You are welcome :-).

Answer (score 7):

Another alternative here: $m+n$ and $m-n$ are either both odd or both even i.e. their product is either odd or divisible by $4$ and $6$ is neither.

Comment: Similar to what @labbhattacharjee suggested.

Answer (score 5):

There's an easier way to do this. So, you know $(m+n)(m-n) = 6$, and $6 = 2 \cdot 3 = 1 \cdot 6$. If $m,n$ are to be whole numbers, then so must $m+n$ and $m-n$. Thus, we could look at the systems of equations that result by setting factors equal to each other:

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
m+n = 2\\ 
m-n=3
\end{matrix}\right. \;\;\;\;\; \left\{\begin{matrix}
m+n = 3\\ 
m-n=2
\end{matrix}\right. \;\;\;\;\; \left\{\begin{matrix}
m+n = 1\\ 
m-n=6
\end{matrix}\right. \;\;\;\;\; \left\{\begin{matrix}
m+n = 6\\ 
m-n=1
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Show that, in none of these cases, you do not have both $m,n$ as whole numbers to get a solution.

Comment: ... for example because the first two imply $2m=5$, the last two $2m=7$.

Answer (score 2):

Seems fine though your proof is long.

As for your question regarding generalization to $6j$.

For the special case where $j$ is odd, we also can't have $m^2-n^2=6j$.

Suppose not, then we have $(m+n)(m-n)=6j$.

If $m+n$ and $m-n$ are both odd, then the LHS is odd but RHS is even.

If $m+n$ and $m-n$ are both even, then LHS is a multiple of $4$, but RHS is not a multiple of $4$.

Comment: Please see my post at : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3613426/424260.

Comment: Please help with my post stated in the last comment. You can help in chatroom alternatively.

Comment: I am working on some other stuff, I might post an answer if I have the time and if it is still not resolved later

Comment: Any sort of help is not coming.

Comment: Sorry late, but is based on implicit proof of $4 \nmid 6j, j \in \{ 2m+1\}, m\in \mathbb{N}$$ \implies 2 \nmid 3j, j \in \{ 2m+1\}, m\in \mathbb{N} $.

Answer (score 1):

The answers already added are pretty good in my opinion, especially the one by @trancelocation. However, since nobody has approached this via congruences yet, I wanted to do the same.

We consider the general case, $m^2-n^2 = 6j, m,n,j \ge 1$. It is an elementary fact that any square is congruent to $0,1$ modulo $4$ according to as it is even or odd. Then, rewriting the equation, we have,

$m^2 = n^2 + 6j \equiv n^2 + 2j \ \bmod 4$

If $n$ is even, we must have $2j \equiv 0 \ \bmod 4 \implies j \equiv 0 \ \bmod 2$.

If $n$ is odd, we again have $2j +1\equiv 1\ \bmod 4 \implies j \equiv 0 \ \bmod 2$.

Hence, the general equation only has solutions if $j$ is even.